# deferred loading of javascript files

Tags: jquery-deferred

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="chart1">
</div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

    // Add a script element as a child of the body 

    function downloadJSAtOnload() {

        var element1 = document.createElement("script");
        element1.src = "js/jquery-1.7.2.js";
        document.body.appendChild(element1);
        var element2 = document.createElement("script");
        element2.src = "js/jquery.jqplot.js";
        document.body.appendChild(element2);
        var element3 = document.createElement("script");
        element3.src = "js/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.js";
        document.body.appendChild(element3);
        var element4 = document.createElement("script");
        element4.src = "js/jqplot.canvasAxisLabelRenderer.js";
        document.body.appendChild(element4);
        var element5 = document.createElement("script");
        element5.src = "js/deferredfunction.js";
        document.body.appendChild(element5);
        //setTimeout("Func1()", 2000);
        //Func1();
        //            $(window).bind("load", function() {
        //                Func1();
        //            });

    }

    function Func1() {



        var plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [[3, 7, 9, 1, 4, 6, 8, 2, 5]]);


    }




    // Check for browser support of event handling capability
    function chk_comp() {
        if (window.addEventListener)
            window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
        else if (window.attachEvent) {
            debugger;
            window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
        }
        else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
    }

    chk_comp();
</script>
```

I'm getting error.i want to call the jquery functions to be called after the page load completes and  it automatically triggers the function "func1()" after all the neceesary .js files loaded but it's not happeneing.please help me

Comment: can anyone answer this plssss?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you want to wait the complete loading of the page before starting loading other scripts. You should load all scripts at the same time, it will be faster.

Then, if the browser supports events, you can trigger *func1()*.

If you often have issues with conditionnal loading, I suggest you use something to achieve it easily : http://yepnopejs.com/